# How to install only specific mysql client functions

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker container and need the abillity of mysqldump and importing sql files to a external mysql server. So i dont need the Server engine in my docker container. I just need the abillity of running mysqlcommands.

So how can i just install this abiolity with minimal space requirement in my docker container?

Comment: What are mysqlcommands?

Comment: from your container you can connect mysql instance with ssh and run the commands.